# The VPN client agent was unable to create the interprocess communication depot in MacOS

Tags: vpn, macos-sierra, cisco-vpn-client

I'm using **MacOS Sierra 10.12.2**
I've installed then upgrade the **Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 4.4.02034**

after couple of hours of using the system an interrupting popup shows randomly and shows this alert: **The VPN client agent was unable to create the interprocess communication depot.**

How can I remove it?

Comment: What version of AnyConnect client are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.4.02034 version

Comment: AnyConnect won't be operational if it fails the creation of IPC depot. System logs should show why AnyConnect failed. Do you have any software installed that would affect creation of sockets or affect the sockets that have been already opened ?

Comment: @Mahesh 
system log or cisco any connect log? can you explain more about it?

Comment: AnyConnect logs to system log.

Comment: I've looked at the system log but nothing appeared about the error

Comment: **osascript**
_Subsystem: com.apple.automation.osascript_tool_run_
`com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.automation.osascript_tool_run
com.apple.message.signature: vpnagentd
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
SenderMachUUID: 45DA9F71-6BF2-3DAD-AF36-AAD812BE87FD`